# how can I get a return value from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

'Requests.java'

```
public Invoice getInvoice() {
        return invoice;}
```

'Invoice.java'

```
public String getInvoiceID() {
        return invoiceID;}
```

class where I want to get the value

```
payInvoiceId.setText(": " + requests.getInvoice().getInvoiceID());
```

Comment: fix Question , Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you either need to instantiate an instance of Invoice within Requests.java or make the "getInvoiceID()" method Static which would allow you to call requests.getInvoiceID(). Static methods can be called without an instance. (See also Math.random)

Comment: making it static worked. Thank you so much!! :))))

Comment: Making everything static is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.